# ng-hide and ng-show alternatives

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

**I am pretty new to this and have no idea how to Google this, so I'm already happy if you could give me a search term.**

When a user clicks on a bag, the carousel and the other bags should disappear and additional information about the selected bag should appear... Just like on [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/) .

Also the URL should change to `<website>/product/<productname>`

I have tried using *ng-show* and *ng-hide,* but that feels rather hackish..

How can this be done with the MEAN stack?

**EDIT: I've went with `ng-view` to achieve my goal**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `ng-show` and `ng-hide` will be used...why does that feel hackish?

Answer (score 2):

I would rather have a separate state for bag's profile and change the state when a bag is clicked instead of using ng-show/ng-hide.

check [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for more info.

Also, take a look at [`ng-if`.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)